# Round by next quarter minutes always

Tags: java

We have a requirement to Round by next quarter minutes in Java code, for example:

1. if current date time is  2020-05-28T10:01:00
   then, round up to next quarter to make it  2020-05-28T10:15:00
2. if current date time is 2020-05-28T10:15:01
   then, round up to next quarter to make it  2020-05-28T10:30:00
3. if current date time is 2020-05-28T10:46:15
   then, round up to next quarter to make it  2020-05-28T11:00:00
4. if current date time is 2020-12-31T23:47:00
   then, round up to next quarter to make it 2021-01-01T00:00:00

Can someone please provide Java code to achieve this. Any help is appreciated.

---

Tried below code but unable to get the output which I'm looking for:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(new Date());
            int round = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) % 15;
            calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, round < 8 ? -round : (15-round));
            calendar.set( Calendar.SECOND, 0 );
            System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post the code you've written so far, Stack Overflow is not a service to write your code for free ;) you must show some effort!

Comment: I do not see the question?

Comment: Since I am new to Java... so asking for help.. but i edited my question with Java code

Comment: FYI, the terribly flawed date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes built into Java 8 and later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be easily done using the [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) class from the [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package, which you should be using anyway<sup>1</sup>.

```
public static LocalDateTime roundUpToQuarter(LocalDateTime datetime) {
    int minutesToAdd = 15 - (datetime.getMinute() % 15);
    return datetime
        .plusMinutes(minutesToAdd)
        .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
}
```

This calculation involving the modulus operator makes sure that we get the number of minutes to add to go to the next full quarter. The `truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES)` call makes in turn sure that all fields smaller than 'minutes' are set to zero.

**Update**: I'm not certain of your exact use case, but, as Basil pointed out, if you want to represent *a moment on the timeline*, then you also need a timezone or offset. This can be done by replacing `LocalDateTime` instances with `ZonedDateTime` in the abovementioned method.

---

<sup>1</sup> The `Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes are obsolete. They *may* work in simple cases, but they *will* cause trouble in more complex cases. See [What's wrong with Java Date & Time API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api).

Comment: C:\Users\*****\javaCode\ProcessDefinitionJavaCode.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
int minutesToAdd = 15 - (now.getMinutes() % 15);
                            ^
  symbol:   method getMinutes()
  location: variable now of type LocalDateTime
1 error

Comment: It's `getMinute` instead of `getMinutes`.

Comment: It's Jre 1.8, strange thing is only ow.getMinutes()  causing issue.
when i tried below to see if error coming for othet thing as well, but below is working fine without error. And yes imported LocalDateTime.
LocalDateTime newTime =  now.plusMinutes(1).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);

Comment: Thanks for help:.
do you know to get the output in some variable. When I am trying to convert,it's throwing an error:
incompatible types: LocalDateTime cannot be converted to Date

Comment: I think I found it:
Date d = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf( newTime);

Comment: Only thing left, if I can pass Input datetime to this request. How can i input the requested datetime?

Comment: Good Answer, except that I cannot think of any scenario where calling `LocalDateTime.now()` is the right thing to do, since that class cannot represent a moment. I suggest changing to [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). See such [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/TbDhlK).

Comment: @BasilBourque It cannot, indeed. But to me, the exact use case of OP was not entirely clear. But judging by the comments it looks like the datetime should be timezone-sensitive. I used `LocalDateTime.now()` as an example.

Comment: @abhishekkaran I've updated the answer, to include a method returning a rounded time.

Comment: I can two issues:
when i pass input as 2020-11-30T23:47:00 , Output is coming as  2020-11-30T23:00:00
expected Output should be 2020-12-01T00:00:00
Second issue: when passing Input as 2020-12-31T23:47:00  , Output is coming as 2020-12-31T23:00:00, actual output should be
2021-01-01T00:00:00  ( i.e next year)

Surprisingly things are working good till Oct end i.e 2020-10-31T23:47:00 is workign and showing output as 2020-11-01T00:00:00.... so not sure what the issue with Nov and Dec

Comment: @abhishekkaran It depends on how you are passing it. How are you passing your input?

Comment: @abhishekkara This occurs due to daylight savings time.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Yes, it was due to Daylight saving. I tested with passing timezone and now it's working as expected... Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(new Date(1609438620000l));
    int fraction = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) / 15;
    switch (fraction) {
    case 0: {
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        break;
    }
    case 1: {
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        break;
    }
    default: {
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
        break;
    }
    }
    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. But I am getting MyClass.java uses or overrides a deprecated API error when try to run your code. Any suggestion?

Comment: You can suppress the warnings. Add below line on top of the method.  

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

Comment: I've updated my answer using Calendar since you're already using it. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks it's working but below I am getting:
Input: 2020-05-30T17:57:07
output: 2020-05-30T18:00:07

Expected Output should be 2020-05-30T18:00:00

Comment: Did you miss `calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);` ?

Comment: Gotcha...I missed it... Thanks a ton. I will verify all scenarios and let u know on this.

Comment: Vijay .... is there way I can Input the dateTime manually in this code to check all scenario? For example if i need to pass "2020-05-31T10:30:00.416-04:00"  as a Input

Comment: FYI, the terribly flawed date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes built into Java 8 and later.

Comment: I can two issues: when i pass input as 2020-11-30T23:47:00 , Output is coming as 2020-11-30T23:00:00 expected Output should be 2020-12-01T00:00:00 Second issue: when passing Input as 2020-12-31T23:47:00 , Output is coming as 2020-12-31T23:00:00, actual output should be 2021-01-01T00:00:00 ( i.e next year) Surprisingly things are working good till Oct end i.e 2020-10-31T23:47:00 is workign and showing output as 2020-11-01T00:00:00.... so not sure what the issue with Nov and Dec –